# All inputs carets misaligned

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-ios

Currently I am working on an application with ionic where caret is getting misaligned with input, its showing above the ion-input only in iOS app, but I was able to detect it using inspection through safari.
here is the ionic info
Ionic:

Ionic CLI : 5.4.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

Cordova CLI : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : ios 6.1.1
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 13 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.2
native-run : 0.2.8 (update available: 1.2.2)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/shoaib/Library/Android/sdk/)
ios-deploy : 1.11.3
ios-sim : 8.0.2
NodeJS : v12.18.4 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm : 6.14.6
OS : macOS Catalina
Xcode : Xcode 11.5 Build version 11E608c

Screen shots attached for with and without keyboard, currently testing on IOS Simulator with iOS 13.5 . Pardon me if am missing something as I am new to ionic.

[image: during inspect input is showing above]

Comment: really looking forward to the solution to this, have been stuck in similar issue since last 2 days